# how to run a shell script on git commit

Tags: git, shell-script, github

1)

i have a shell script which basically contains some(database testing and integrating test code) ,

but i have to run this shell script when ever there is commit (or any change ) in my git repo the script should execute how can i achieve this

os. Debian  6.0.1 amazon ec2

i am trying something like Travis for continues integration ..

2)

for GUI testing in Debian like O.S which is better selenium or casper.js

or is the any other beter alternative

so please help me

Comment: You shouldn't ask two questions in a single 'topic'.

Comment: yes sure next time i will surely take care of it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answer to your first question: You want to use git-hooks. On the repository server, browse to the bare git repo directory and modify the `hooks/post-commit` file (and make it executable with `chmod +x hooks/post-commit`)

```
#!/bin/bash

read oldrev newrev refname
## Debugging stuff
#echo "Old revision: $oldrev" >> /home/git/push_log.txt
#echo "New revision: $newrev" >> /home/git/push_log.txt
#echo "Reference name: -${refname}-" >> /home/git/push_log.txt

command_line_script__or_command_to_run_travis_integration.sh
```

This will start the script whenever you commit in the repository. There are many different kinds of hooks, which are all documented in `man githooks`. Probably you also want to take a look at `post-receive`, it will run the script whenever you push to the repository.

Comment: If you find my answer useful, please mark it as an answer :)

Comment: will this work if some other person from other terminal commit the code .. or will it work only when the commit is from my PC only

Comment: means if a person sitting on other PC and commits the code then will this run (the repository are the same)

Comment: This will only work when the user who set this up will do a commit. I don't know your workflow, but you are probably better off doing a `post-receive` hook, which will run when there has been a push to the repo. If you set this up on the repository server it will run for all users who push to the repo.

Comment: If you set this up on the repository server?? can u please tell me detail that how can i set it up to an repository server

Comment: There is an excellent guide on http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server